# mysql hot add memory

Tags: mysql, performance, memory-usage

Is it possible for currently running jobs in MySQL to utilize memory that's been hot added? It looks like when memory is hot added to the VM the currently running jobs are not utilizing the additional memory.

Comment: What OS distribution, version, virtualization platform, hypervisor?

Comment: Win 2012 R2 and VMware 5.5.

Comment: How much RAM did you hot-add?

Answer (score 2):

Schedule downtime and reboot your VM. Memory hot-add isn't really that great.

You may have other issues in your VMware environment like a hard memory limit assigned to the VM. Make sure that you don't have any.